# Young adult story about an inventor who creates the first “Faster Than Light” technology

Tags: story-identification

Years ago I read a “Young Adult” Science fiction story about an inventor who creates the first “Faster Than Light” technology. This FTL mechanism created an inertia-less bubble around a person or object and could propel them to multiples of lightspeed.  He first used it for terrestrial travel and found it to be so fast it was indistinguishable from teleportation.

In the story, powerful political and financial interests try to stop him from making his invention freely available to the entire world. Toward the end of the story, he and his crew use it to travel to a planet orbiting the star, Alpha Centauri, and make first contact with a friendly humanoid race who wear what seems to be 1920 style straw boater hats.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I would like to know the title and author. I feel it was by a well-known author of juvenile science fiction, but I can’t remember who it is.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was this a book or a short story? Also, in roughly what year did you read it?

Comment: Short novel. around 1999.